# check if last row in pandas df.iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I check last row in Python pandas df.itterows() during its iteration?

My code :

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
...     # I want to check last row in df iterrows(). somelike row[0].tail(1)
```

Comment: Could you add an example input and desired outcome. It's a bit hard to grasp what you want.

Comment: I think it explain enough. because I just want to check if it last row in pandas dataframe during iteration in df.iterrows().

Comment: Well your question said "check", but your comment said "detect". Do you mean you simply want to now if the "current row" inside the iteration is the last row?

Comment: I am sorry. yes I mean check. and that is what I mean.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use

```
for i, (index, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows()):
    if i == len(df) - 1:
        pass
```

Comment: This is works. but how if we use pandas dataframe itself or on row attribute itself? is it possible?

Comment: @Gunslinger_ no!... there is no attribute on the row itself that identifies the row as the last row.  As a matter of fact, `iterrows` alters the internal objects, making it appear as if the dataframe is a collection of rows when it is actually a collection of columns.

Answer (score 17):

The pandas.DataFrame class has a subscriptable `index` attribute.  So one can check the index of the row when iterating over the row using `iterrows()` against the last value of the df.index attribute like so:

```
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if idx == df.index[-1]:
        print('This row is last')
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.